# Can I substitute condensed milk for evaporated milk in icing?

Tags: substitutions, icing, evaporated-milk

My icing recipe for German chocolate cake pecan icing calls for evaporated milk, but I only have condensed milk. Can I use the condensed milk instead?

If so, do I need to make any adjustments to it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.

- If you have *unsweetened* condensed milk, that is another name for evaporated milk and they are interchangeable.

---

- If you have *sweetened* condensed milk, you can use one 14 oz can to replace one cup of evaporated milk and one cup of granulated sugar.

Comment: By 'oz' do you mean weight ounces, or fluid ounces? I ask because the other two measurements you gave are both cups (volume based). Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @mech I was referring to a particular can size which is stated as 14 oz. on the label.

Comment: @mech It would be fluid ounces.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Condensed milk and evaporated milk have the same consistency (almost) simply because both of them are made by the same process of evaporating 60% of the water content but the similarity ends there. Because sweet condensed milk contains added sugar you can [substitute condensed milk](http://www.chihollandia.com/can-hollandia-evap-milk-be-a-substitute-for-condensed-milk/) with evaporated milk by adding some sugar in it.

Comment: Hi Madison and welcome! The last sentence of your answer is confusing and, in fact, opposite of what your linked reference states. Please edit to correct the provided information.